# Summation with indexing variable in term

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am trying to solve $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j2^j$$ but I don't know how to proceed with the $j$ in front of $2^j$. What is making it difficult for me is it is an indexing variable, so I don't think I can factor it out. How would I proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: If that sum is $S$, then what is $2S - S$?

Comment: Also this might help overall: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetico-geometric_series

Answer (score 4):

Sum of a geometric progression:
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\quad(x\ne1)$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1}=\frac{(n+1)x^n(x-1)-(x^{n+1}-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$
Multiply by $x$:
$$x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+nx^n=\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}$$
Set $x=2$:
$$\sum_{j=0}^nj2^j=(n-1)2^{n+1}+2$$
Oops, I misread the question. OK, now substitute $n-1$ for $n$:
$$\boxed{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j2^j=(n-2)2^{n}+2}$$
To verify the result by mathematical induction, note that
$$[(n-1)2^{n+1}+2]-[(n-2)2^{n}+2]=n2^n$$

Comment: Note $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}$ versus $\sum_{j=0}^n$.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that the OP's upper limit was $n-1$ instead of $n$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* The triangular array ($n = 6$ shown)
$$
\begin{array}{crcrcrcrcr}
&1\cdot2^1 &+ &2\cdot2^2 &+ &3\cdot2^3 &+ &4\cdot2^4 &+ &5\cdot 2^5 \\[8pt]
= &2^1 &+ &2^2 &+ &2^3 &+ &2^4 &+ &2^5 \\
  &    &+ &2^2 &+ &2^3 &+ &2^4 &+ &2^5 \\
  &    &  &    &+ &2^3 &+ &2^4 &+ &2^5 \\
  &    &  &    &  &    &+ &2^4 &+ &2^5 \\
  &    &  &    &  &    &  &    &+ &2^5 
\end{array}
$$
can be summed by columns first or by rows first.

Answer (score 0):

$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{xj}=\frac{2^{nx}-1}{2^x-1}$

$dS/dx= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}j\cdot \ln 2 \cdot 2^{xj}=\frac{(2^x-1)(\ln 2 \cdot n\cdot 2^{nx})-\ln2 \cdot 2^x\cdot(2^{nx}-1)}{(2^x-1)^2}$

$\frac{1}{\ln 2}\frac{dS}{dx}|_{x=1}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} j \cdot 2^j= 2n\cdot 2^n-2\cdot(2^n-1)=2(n-1)2^{n}+2$

$0\cdot 1s+ 1 \cdot 2 +2 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 8+...$

$f(n)=2(n-2)2^{n-1}+2$

Nont sure why I got an off by one error, but after compensating for it, we can prove $f(n)$ works via induction.

Note $f(1)=0, f(2)=2, f(3)=10$, ..., i.e. this satisfies the sum for the first few values.

$f(n+1)=2(n-1)\cdot 2^n+2$

$f(n+1)-f(n)= n2^n$

---

$Q(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\cdot 2^k$

$Q(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot 2^k$

$Q(n+1)-Q(n)=n\cdot 2^n$

---

So $f(1)=Q(1)=0$

$f(n+1)-f(n)=Q(n+1)-Q(n)=n\cdot 2^n$

So if $f(n)=Q(n)$ then $f(n+1)=Q(n+1)$

and the sum is $f(n)$ holds by induction.